# Angular EventEmitter observer does not get called

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I set up a small part of my project, which I'm struggling with: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ee7v5t

If the link gets invalid, here the least amount of code to understand the problem:

**options.component.html**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-options',
  templateUrl: './options.component.html',
  ...
})
export class OptionsComponent implements OnInit {
  country: any;

  ...

  receiveCountry(country: any) {
    this.country = country;
    console.log("2");
  }
}
```

**options.component.html**

```
<app-country-selector (countrySelectedEvent)="receiveCountry($event)"></app-country-selector>
```

**country-selector.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-country-selector',
  ...
})
export class CountrySelectorComponent implements OnInit {
   @Output() countrySelectedEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

...

  onOptionSelected($event) { //gets called by angular material autocomplete
    let selectedCountry = this.countries.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() == $event.option.value.toLowerCase());
    this.countrySelectedEvent.emit(selectedCountry);
    console.log("1");
  }
}
```

I want the `options.component` to get called when in the `country-selector.component` a value in the autocompletion is selected.
I want to achieve this by using the EventEmitter, and did connected the functions in the html part of the code according to the angular documentation.

I added two `console.logs` but only see one, the other part that's confusing me is that the EventEmitter object has no observers in his arrays.

Everything should be correct but something is off and I can't figure out what.

Comment: Please put a [mre] *in the question*.

Comment: I think I did this. Its the stackblitz link. There is the code and the problem is reproducable there. Is something else missing?

Comment: It's not *in the question* - off-site links rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your stackblitz, remove CountrySelectorComponent from bootstrap section in app.module.ts.

You should put all common components into declarations section

> bootstrap—the root component that Angular creates and inserts into the index.html host web page.